# trying to record a video with javascript using a webcam without a service

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, record

i am trying to create a web page that displays the camera at start-up when press a button starts recording and press button to stop recording the play the video after it stops recording. i have it showing the camera but the button functions are currently not working. i will show u my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Display Webcam Stream</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
  </head>         
  <body>
    <button id="btn-start-recording" onclick="go()">Start Recording now</button>
    <button id="btn-stop-recording" onclick="stop()">stop recording</button>
    <div id="container">
      <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="375"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="recording.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My javascript:

```
   var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
   if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
     navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
       .then(function (stream) {
         video.srcObject = stream;
       })
       .catch(function (err0r) {
         console.log("Something went wrong!");
         alert("you need a webcam and micophone to record a Video");
         document.getElementById("btn-start-recording").disabled = true;
         //document.getElementById("btn-stop-recording").disabled = true;
       });
   }
   var newvideo = document.getElementById("video");

   //startup();
   function stop() {
    var stream = video.srcObject;
    var tracks = stream.getTracks();

    for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
      var track = tracks[i];
      track.stop();
    }
    stopRecording();
    alert("started");
    // var create = "false";
    // recording(create);
  }

  function stopRecording() {
    var chunks = [];
      // var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4' });
      let blob = recorder.getBlob();
    var videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    if(videoURL != null) {
      video.src = videoURL;
      video.play();
    }
    else
      alert("Error didn't create video please try again");
  }

  function gorecording() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: true
  }).then(async function(stream) {
      let recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
          type: 'video'
      });
      recorder.startRecording();

      const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));
      await sleep(3000);

      recorder.stopRecording(function() {
          let blob = recorder.getBlob();
          invokeSaveAsDialog(blob);
      });
  });
  }

  function draw () {
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

  function startRecording() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var video = document.getElementById("videoElement");
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "black", "white", "green"];
draw();
    //var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    alert("helloooo");
  }

  function SstartRecording() {        
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
alert("helloooo");
var video = document.querySelector("video");

var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "black", "white", "green"];
draw();

var videoStream = canvas.captureStream(30);
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(videoStream);

var chunks = [];
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
  chunks.push(e.data);
};

mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
  var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4' });
  chunks = [];
  var videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  video.src = videoURL;
};

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
  chunks.push(e.data);
};

mediaRecorder.start();
setInterval(draw, 300);
setTimeout(function (){ mediaRecorder.stop(); }, 5000);
alert("hello");
}
  //}
  function go() {
    //var create = "true";
      startRecording();
    //recording(create);
  }  

  function recording(create) { 
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
    var videoStream = canvas.captureStream(30); 
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(videoStream);
    var chunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
  };

  mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
   var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4' }); 
    chunks = [];
    var videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    video.src = videoURL;
  };

  if (create == "true") {
    mediaRecorder.start();
  } else {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
  }
  }
```

And my css :

```
.display-cover {'
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    position: relative;
}
/* 
#container
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30px;
} */
#videoElement {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
body{
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any erros on the console?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a minimal example (remove all code not needed and format your code)?